# nicematrix: How to refer to the same \tabularnote without creating a new one?

Tags: pdftex, nicematrix

Consider following latex fragment:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{A caption.}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc}\toprule
\textbf{Titel 1}    &\textbf{Titel 2} &\textbf{Titel 3}&\textbf{Titel 4}    \\\midrule
A\tabularnote{Note 1}       & a & b & c \\
B\tabularnote{Note 1}       & a & b & c \\
C\tabularnote{Note 1}   & a & b & c \\\midrule

X\tabularnote{Note 2}       & a & b & c \\
Y\tabularnote{Note 2}       & a & b & c \\
Z\tabularnote{Note 2}   & a & b & c \\\midrule

I\tabularnote{Note 3}       & a & b & c \\
J\tabularnote{Note 3}       & a & b & c \\
K\tabularnote{Note 3}   & a & b & c \\\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
```

It works, but it does create 9 tabularnotes although elements of each group share the same tabularnote-content. How exactly can I create a single tabularnote, that can be shared by several other entries in the list?

Comment: (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). At this time, this is not possible with `nicematrix` (sorry) but it's a good idea and I will program something for the next version (if you have a suggestion of syntax, tell me). For the moment, if you actually need features of `nicematrix` for your tabular, you can use for the notes the classical `threeparttable` with `nicematrix` (there is a remark in the doc of `nicematrix` concerning `threeparttable`).

Comment: @F.Pantigny Really appreciating your comment, no problem, really. It's already very nice (-:

As for the syntax, what about: Tabular notes with the same content are automatically recognized and referred to the same footnote (if wanted), so probably something like:

Entry 1 \tabularnote{foo}
Entry 2 \tabularnote{foo}


will both refer to the same footnote [a]..
_

Comment: I have uploaded on CTAN a new version of `nicematrix` (v 6.8 of 2022-03-11) with that behaviour.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Very nice! I really appreciate it. Have a good day'! (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.8 of 2022-03-11), several commands `\tabularnote` with the same argument generate only one note under the tabular (but, of course, all the references are composed).

It's possible to disable that feature with the key `notes/detect-duplicates=false`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A caption.}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc}\toprule
\textbf{Titel 1}    &\textbf{Titel 2} &\textbf{Titel 3}&\textbf{Titel 4}    \\\midrule
A\tabularnote{Note 1}       & a & b & c \\
B\tabularnote{Note 1}       & a & b & c \\
C\tabularnote{Note 1}   & a & b & c \\\midrule

X\tabularnote{Note 2}       & a & b & c \\
Y\tabularnote{Note 2}       & a & b & c \\
Z\tabularnote{Note 2}   & a & b & c \\\midrule

I\tabularnote{Note 3}       & a & b & c \\
J\tabularnote{Note 3}       & a & b & c \\
K\tabularnote{Note 3}   & a & b & c \\\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: (-: very nice'!